# Click event not firing when View inserted into Collection view

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to add a couple of buttons to my page at run time. The buttons are created and pushed into a containerView. See the addButtons function below.

Given a controller:

```
RE.MenuController =  Em.ArrayController.extend


  addButtons: ->
    console.log "addButtons"
    container = Ember.ContainerView.create()
    container.append()

    prevButton = RE.ButtonView.create()
    container.pushObject(prevButton)
```

and a view:

```
RE.ButtonView = Em.View.extend
  classNames: 'menuLink'
  tagName: 'button'
  templateName: 'button'

  click: (e) ->
    alert 'button clicked'
```

I'm never seeing the expected alert when I click on the button. Why wouldn't the click event be firing?

The html for the button looks like:

```
<button id="ember420" class="ember-view menuLink">TEST</button>
```

There's no data-ember-action there.

Should I be using this approach or use the action helper in the template?

thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 1):

`Ember.View` event handlers (in your case, the `click` function) are invoked by Ember's `EventDispatcher` which listens on the application root element and delegates events. The event dispatcher is only instantiated by an `Ember.Application`.  Are you creating an `Application`? If not, the events will never be dispatched.